# How to create a reusable input field using react?

Tags: reactjs, forms, react-functional-component

I have InputField component which accepts various props like type,placeholder,value, etc. i am trying to create a form using InputField component. I can easily pass props from form but i cant save input values to my state.
Here is my code.

> InputField.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const InputField = ({ value, label, placeholder, type, onChange }) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    onChange(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      {label && <label htmlFor="input-field">{label}</label>}
      <input
        type={type}
        value={value}
        className="form-control"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default InputField;
```

> AddProductForm.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Button } from "reactstrap";
import InputField from "../UI/InputField";

const AddProductForm = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({ name: "", price: "" });
  const { name, price } = inputValue;

  const handleChange = (inputValue) => {
    setInputValue({ name: inputValue, price: inputValue });
    console.log(inputValue);
  };
  return (
    <Form>
      <InputField
        type="text"
        value={name}
        placeholder="Product Name"
        label="Name"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <InputField
        type="number"
        value={price}
        placeholder="Add Price"
        label="Price"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <Button color="primary">Add</Button>{" "}
      <Button color="secondary">Cancel</Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default AddProductForm;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try passing from `InputField` `event` instead of `value`.
Then in the `handler` you can take the `input name` and understand which field should be updated.

Of course, by first adding `name` field for `input` as shown below:

**InputField.js**

```
import React  from "react";

const InputField = ({ value, label, name, placeholder, type, onChange }) => (
  <div className="form-group">
    {label && <label htmlFor="input-field">{label}</label>}
    <input
      type={type}
      value={value}
      name={name}
      className="form-control"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={onChange}
    />
  </div>
);

export default InputField;
```

**AddProductForm.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import InputField from "../UI/InputField";

const AddProductForm = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState({ name: "", price: "" });
  const { name, price } = inputValue;

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInputValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      [name]: value,
    }));
    console.log(inputValue);
  };

  return (
     <Form>
       <InputField
         type="text"
         value={name}
         placeholder="Product Name"
         label="Name"
         name="name"
         onChange={handleChange}
       />
       <InputField
         type="number"
         value={price}
         placeholder="Add Price"
         label="Price"
         name="price"
         onChange={handleChange}
       />
       <Button color="primary">Add</Button>{" "}
       <Button color="secondary">Cancel</Button>
     </Form>
  );
};

export default AddProductForm;
```

Answer (score 2):

tools react hooks,[mantine/core components]
[1]: https://mantine.dev/ yup schema and  react hooks form for form validations
styled components
**shared-input-text-filed.tsx**

```
import { TextInput as customTextInput } from '@mantine/core'; 
import styled from 'styled-components';
type TextInputProps = {
  key: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  variant?: 'primary' | 'danger' | 'warning';
  size?: 'sm' | 'lg';
  className?: string;
  icon?: any;
  register: any;
  required?: boolean;
  error?: string;

};

    const StyledTextInput = styled(customTextInput)``;
    
    export const SharedTextFiled= (props: TextInputProps) => {
      return (
        <StyledTextInput
          variant={props.variant}
          type="text"
          classNames={{
            icon: 'border-r w-16 text-black h-full flex  ',
            withIcon: 'items-center',
            input: 'indent-0',
          }}
          className={props.className}
          disabled={props.disabled}
          key={props.key}
          required={props.required}
          error={props.error}
          icon={props.icon ? <>{props.icon}</> : ''}
          {...props.register}
        ></StyledTextInput>
      );
    };
```

**component-form.tsx**

```
import { SharedTextInput} from '../../../shared/components/shared-text-input-filed';
<SharedTextInput
                        register={{ ...register('name') }}
                        className="mb-2"
                        icon={lang}
                        required={true}
                        error={errors?.name?.name?.message}
                      />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with TypeScript:

```
import { InputHTMLAttributes, forwardRef, ComponentProps } from "react";
import cn from "classnames";

type TInput = InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> & {
  label?: string;
  wrapperClasses?: ComponentProps<"div">["className"];
};

export const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, TInput>(
  ({ wrapperClasses, label, className, id, name, value, ...rest }, ref) => {
    return (
      <div className={wrapperClasses}>
        {label && (
          <label htmlFor={id} className="pl-1 mb-1 inline-block font-semibold">
            {label}
          </label>
        )}
        <input
          ref={ref}
          id={id}
          name={name}
          value={value}
          className={cn(
            "border-2 border-primary bg-red transition h-12 px-5 rounded-md focus:outline-none w-full text-black text-lg",
            className
          )}
          {...rest}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Then we'd just use it like this:

```
 <Input
      ref={inputRef}
      label="Username"
      type="text"
      placeholder="Enter your username"
      wrapperClasses="mb-5"
      value={username}
      onChange={(e) => setUsername(e.target.value)}
      classname="py-5" // <-- override default input css defined in Input component
  />
```